# ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED - serverkess package

Tags: node.js, openssl, serverless-framework

I am getting `error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported` for a serverless package command.

Have referred to multiple SO questions and other documents. Most of them suggest the following:

1. **Downgrading node version to any LTS lesser than 17**: 
   Downgrading the node version creates a lot of library compatibility issues. For example, one of the many errors I get from the node-fetch library during webpacking is  `Can't resolve 'node:util' in <project-directory>\node_modules\node-fetch\src`
2. **Set Node to use openssl legacy provider**: 
   Since the newer versions of node use the encryption algorithms supported by the newer openssl but the libraries in the project still (guessing) only support the algorithms supported by openssl 1.1, which is the main reason behind the `ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED` issue, we need to override node's default encryption algorithms to the ones supported by openssl 1.1 by setting NODE_OPTIONS to `--openssl-legacy-provider`. This solution is working for react projects or even frontend frameworks like ionic where the node options can be easily overridden in the scripts in package.json or the documentation of ionic tells us how to set it so that it can pick it up during build stage. But this does not work for backend framework libraries like `serverless`. I am not sure how the node options can be overridden for `serverless` because setting it as an environment variable is not working nor can I find any documentation.

Comment: Did you try switching to a different version with node version manager by doing something like: `nvm use 16`?

Comment: Hello @mostlycryptic, yes. I had tried to downgrade it to an LTS version in the 16s. It had multiple compatibility issues with the libraries. Please refer to the point 1 of my question.